# Can't Access Azure Databricks Root / Local Storage

Tags: azure, permissions, databricks

So i am trying to create a workflow for my project but I'm unable to move forward with the code as there are a lot of "**Permission Denied**" errors that I'm getting even for trivial commands like **"os.listdir()"**.
Basically, anything that i want to write to local storage [ /databricks/driver ,etc] throws is this error.
I am unable to write files or save files in this workspace to a local directory.

Permissions to "**Can Manage**" but still am facing this error.

Any help to access this directory, like where to set this permission would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution
While creating a cluster, i needed to untick the "Enable authentication..." checkbox